# How to parse "stringified" python objects from file back into python objects?

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to parse a file that includes the string representations of python objects.  As in

```
outfile = open("out.txt", "w")
example_string_tuple = (u'bretagne tr\xe9minou 23archiefdingen', u'chicago, il')

# Instead of doing something like this:
outfile.write("\t".join(example_string_tuple).encode("utf-8"))

# I just did this:
outfile.write(str(example_string_tuple))
```

So now in my textfile I have lines that look like this

(u'bretagne tr\xe9minou 23archiefdingen', u'chicago, il')

Note that the unicode is not in utf-8, it's in python's native encoding.

How do I properly parse these lines like that back into the original tuples (without messing up the encoding)? (I'm using python 2.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("""(u'bretagne tr\xe9minou 23archiefdingen', u'chicago, il')""")
(u'bretagne tr\xe9minou 23archiefdingen', u'chicago, il')
```

But use [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) next time.